# Set value to model in view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a bunch of templates/views that consist of labels and inputs. I want to set the label values into the controller models (`$scope.data.details` which is an array).

Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/XqtyFKKNuo8upzPuaImo?p=preview

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label set-model="data.details[0]">Label 1</label>
    <input type=text/>
    {{ data.details[0] }}
    <label set-model="data.details[1]">Label 2</label>
    <input type=text/>
  </body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    details: []
  };
});

app.directive('setModel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // var pair = JSON.parse(attrs)
      scope[attrs.setModel] = element.html();
      console.log(scope);
      // console.log();
    }
  };
})
```

So basically:

> data.details[0] = "Label 1"
>
> data.details[1] = "Label 2"
>
> ...

I know I could do this in `ng-init` but it would be a long list on top. I want to do it **inline** in the `<label>` itself.

But right now it doesn't work as `$scope` basically shows this in Developer Console:

```
data: Object
data.details[0]: "Label 1"
data.details[1]: "Label 2"
```

So it didn't put `details` as a key inside `data` object but it created a new key `data.details[0]` completely. Also the `data` structure could be different later on so I don't want to *hardcode* anything.

How do I fix this?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does not work this way because when you get key like this 'attrs.setModel' it take whole string which means it takes `data.details[0]` you either resolve this with another javascript code just simply using `scope` attribute of directive like this

```
app.directive('setModel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {model : '=setModel'},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // var pair = JSON.parse(attrs)
      scope.model = element.html();
      console.log(scope);
    }
  };
})
```

right now your directive take parent scope object instead of string so any value change on this affect parent scope object as well...

here is working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ErNBgsKIaYvJs6uX6CiR?p=preview)...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label set-model="{{data.details[0]}}">Label 1</label>
    <input type="text"/>
    {{ data.details[0] }}
    <label set-model="{{data.details[1]}}">Label 2</label>
    <input type=text/>
  </body>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/d9lMXWJDUG6yTxsXFD33?p=preview

If you want result in array only try something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/KZS1wO1cIvEo7sUpWoDU?p=preview